# Sequences for which $\prod (1-z^n)^{a(n)}$ is a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, special-functions, integer-sequences

This is mostly a reference request.

I'm working with complex coefficients, although all I have in mind have integer coefficients.

Let $a=(a(n))_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence, say of integers (I have non-negative integers in mind), although things would make sense with complex numbers. The infinite product $\Phi_a(z)=\prod_n(1-z^n)^{a(n)}$ naturally lies in the ring of power series $\mathbf{C}[\![z]\!]$, and $a$ is determined by $\Phi_a$. Say that $a$ is **special** if $\Phi_a$ is a polynomial.

> Is there a standard terminology for the assignment $a\mapsto \Phi_a$ or the inverse map $\Phi_a\mapsto a$? for what I call "special" sequences? Is there a study of special sequences (they seem far from arbitrary), notably involving the Möbius function $\mu$, or general facts about their asymptotics? Relevant keywords/references would be welcome.

I've seen the assignment $\Phi$ at several places, e.g. related to partitions or modular forms, but the emphasis was not on special sequences, but rather simple-minded $a$ giving rise to interesting $\Phi_a$, while I'm rather interested in the opposite: interesting $a$ giving rise to simple-minded $\Phi_a$.

Examples of naturally occurring "special" sequences $a$ are notably the function $n\mapsto a_d(n)$, the dimension of the degree $n$ graded component of the free Lie algebra on $d$ generators, for which $\Phi_a(z)=1-dz$ (OEIS: for $d=2$ [A001037](https://oeis.org/A001037): 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 30, 56, 99, 186..., for $d=3$ [A027376](https://oeis.org/A027376): 3, 3, 8, 18, 48, 116, 312, 810, 2184...), see also [Wikipedia: Cyclotomic identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_identity). Other examples (among others): [A125951](https://oeis.org/A125951): 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 10, 15, 26, 42, 74, 121, 212, 357... and [A020999](https://oeis.org/A020999) for which such a formula $\prod (1-z^n)^{a(n)}=$*(polynomial)* is explicitly mentioned in both cases.

Comment: When $a_n$ is negative I have seen this called the Euler transform before. See e.g. here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html

Comment: If $R$ is a unique factorization domain of polynomials over some finite field, then the zeta function $\zeta_R(z) = \sum_{f \in R, \hbox{ monic}} z^{\mathrm{deg}(f)}$ is equal to the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty ( 1-z^n)^{a_n}$ where $a_n$ is the number of irreducible polynomials in $R$ of degree $n$ (this is the generating function form of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).  In many cases the Weil conjectures apply and make $\zeta_R$ a rational function. With a bit of algebraic number theory one can generalise beyond the UFD case to Dedekind domains.

Comment: If one just takes logs and compares coefficients, then the condition for the sequence $a$ to be special is that $na(n)$ must equal $\sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \alpha_j^{n/d}$, where $\epsilon_j =\pm 1$ and $\alpha_j$ are complex numbers.  (This is in the case that the product is a rational function.  For a polynomial, the $\epsilon_j$ are all $1$.)